# Android. Как сделать активным касание в любую часть экрана?

Tags: java, android

У меня на экране есть несколько edit кнопок. После их заполнения нужно, чтобы весь экран стал активным и при нажатии на любую часть экрана переходило на следующий экран. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText et;
EditText et_2;
LinearLayout main_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    main_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    main_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (et.getText().length() > 0 && et_2.getText().length() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onTouch работает", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
   }
}
```

### main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```